# How can I navigate outside of components in react-router-1.0.3 in React's render()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to route to another path in the render function in react-router-1.0.3. I can redirect the user by providing a link using:

```
render(
       <Link to={`/${this.props.params.projectSlug}/`}>
           Please follow this link to access your workspace.
       </Link>
      )
```

But I cant seem to programmatically forward to this link. I tried:

```
render(
      <Router history={browserHistory} routes=
          {`/${this.props.params.projectSlug}/`}/>
      )
```

How can I programmatically forward to a relative path in react-router 1.0.3?

Comment: React's latest version is 0.14.7, 1.0.3 doesn't exist. You might be talking about react-router? I'm also not sure what your second snippet is supposed to be doing.

Comment: @CarlVitullo I updated my question, I meant the react-router version. I want to programmatically redirect in the render function. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Is that the render function for a component? The syntax is very wrong if it is. You also can't redirect in a render function, render _cannot_ have any side effects because it gets run for a lot of different reasons.

Comment: @user2212461 where's the rest of your code? Just the render call is not really enough. If you need a redirect, use an actual [`<Redirect>`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#redirect) component in your routers instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrade router to the latest version if you don't mind;
Then, they strictly clarify how to do it [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md).

```
// Your main file that renders a <Router>:
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import routes from './app/routes'

render(
  <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />,
  mountNode
)
```

&

```
// Somewhere like a Redux middleware or Flux action:
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

// Go to /some/path.
browserHistory.push('/some/path')

// Go back to previous location.
browserHistory.goBack()
```